# Get UTC offset of time string without string manipulation

Tags: ruby, time

I have a time string that looks like this: `time = "7:00 PM -0500"`

The offset of this is clearly `-0500`, and I can get that by doing `utc_offset = time[-5..-1]`

However, I want to do this with the existing Ruby Time functionality, instead of using string manipulation.

This needs to work for all time zones, so I can't hardcode a timezone or offset anywhere.  How can I take a string in the format `"<hour>:<minutes> <am/pm> <offset>"`, parse it, and get the correct offset just using functionality in the `Time` class?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html) should help you next time, for this your question possible answer is:

```
require 'time'
time = "7:00 PM -0500"
Time.parse(time).strftime "%z"
 => "-0500"
```

**UPD**

If `Time.parse` return just your local timezone(in some ruby-versions), you can also try this:

```
require 'time'
time = "7:00 PM -0500"
DateTime.parse(time).strftime "%z"
=> "-0500"
```

Comment: `parse` method is present just in some ruby versions. Check the link you posted.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  `Time.parse(time)` converts the time into UTC, so then getting `strftime "%z"` just returns the offset of the UTC time which is `"+0000"`

Comment: @123 your variable `time` the same as you put in your question?

Comment: @Ursus In which version of Ruby this method does not work for you? Cause I check it from version 1.9.3.

Comment: I tried 2.3.1 but even 2.2.0 of your link, there is no `parse` method

Comment: @Ursus I do not know for what reason this method is not described but this exist.

Comment: Yes, sure. The issue is in which version? not in all the versions, too bad.

Comment: @AlexGolubenko this is very strange. It works if I require 'time', even if I should'nt. I don't know why. Anyway, sorry, I can't remove the downvote, too much time is passed :(

Comment: @AlexGolubenko I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 as well...no idea why this doesn't work.  `Time.parse("7:00 PM -0500").strftime("%z")` returns `"+0000"`

Comment: When ‘time’ is required, Time is extended with additional methods for parsing and converting Times.                                https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html